# Pytest: Missing the logic of how to develop a basic pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I wrote this basic function:

```
def cons(a, b):
        return (a,b)

def car(tuple_name):
        return tuple_name[0]

def cdr(tuple_name):
        return tuple_name[1]

print(car(cons(3,5)))
```

I want to implement a testing framework to start properly testing my functions. Someone told me pytest was a good place to start.

From reading examples, I think if I were to implement pytest with this code, it should look something like this:

```
def cons(a, b):
        return (a,b)

def car(tuple_name):
        return tuple_name[0]

def cdr(tuple_name):
        return tuple_name[1]


def test_car(input1):
    assert car(input1) == car(input1)
    assert cdr(input1) == cdr(input1)


print(test_car((3,4)))
```

I know there are two (related) problems with this:

1. When you run the code, it just returns None
2. I'm not doing the testing right (because assert car(input1) = car(input1) will never fail right).

So can someone show me what I'm doing wrong here, how to implement a pytest into these functions. I was also wondering should I have built a class here, but I think that's a different issue.

Comment: Perhaps this might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etosV2IWBF0 (Python Testing 101 with pytest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should run test by following command:

   `python3 -m pytest test.py`
2. You should remove `print(test_car((3,4)))`
3. You should separately test car and cdr functions
4. You should specify function inputs by `@pytest.mark.parametrize` decorator

Final sample with a test for `car` functions is this:

```
import pytest

def cons(a, b):
    return (a, b)


def car(tuple_name):
    return tuple_name[0]


def cdr(tuple_name):
    return tuple_name[1]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("input1, output1", [((3, 4), 3), ((5, 4), 5)])
def test_car(input1, output1):
    assert car(input1) == output1
```

It has two test cases. First test case has input `(3, 4)` and output `3`. Second has input `(5, 4)` and output `5`.